# Bits mirroring in memory

Tags: c, bit

When i'm trying to print every bit in a number stored in uint64_t the bits are the same after bit number 32.

For example if i have read 3 which is 011 when i print it is 1100000...11000000.
The number appears to be "mirrored" after bit number 32.
When i'm printing the number with printf it is 3
Why is this happening?

```
long long int memory;
scanf("%lld",&memory);
for(int i = 63;i>=0;i--){
       long long int nr = (1<<i);
       if((memory & nr)==0)
          printf("%d",0);
        else
          printf("%d",1);
   }
```

Comment: In the future, always provide a [mre] when asking why existing code is not working. This should include a complete runnable program, not a fragment.

Comment: It's repeated, not mirrored.

Comment: Try to use `unsigned` when doing any bit twiddling. In this case, `unsigned long long memory` and `unsigned long long nr = (1ULL << i);`. Using types from `<stdint.h>` is also a good idea (`uint64_t`).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `1<<i`, `1` is an `int`, and the expression is not defined by the C standard when the value of `i` is the number of bits in an `int` or greater.

Change it to `(unsigned long long int) 1 << i` or `1ull << i`. (This presumes your C implementation uses two’s complement, which essentially all modern implementations do. Otherwise, examining the bits of signed integers is a bit trickier.)

Comment: Also, use unsigned types or `1<<63` will be undefined.

Comment: Better do `unsigned long long int`.  Using signed integers when doing bit-fiddling is a little bit "wonky"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the shift as other users mentioned.

But I would implemnt it another way:

```
#define  SetMSBit(type) (((~(type)0) >> 1) ^ (~(type)0))

void printBits64(const uint64_t val)
{
    char ch;
    for(uint64_t mask = SetMSBit(uint64_t); mask; mask >>= 1)
    {
        printf("%c", (val & mask) ? '1' : '0');
    }
}
```